# How to flatten a 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have such an object

```
GrayScale = new float[,] {
    {  0.3f,  0.3f,  0.3f,  0.0f,  0.0f },
    {  0.6f,  0.6f,  0.6f,  0.0f,  0.0f },
    {  0.1f,  0.1f,  0.1f,  0.0f,  0.0f },
    {  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f },
    {  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f }
};
```

and I simply want to make it like the following:

```
var greyScale = new MAGCOLOREFFECT
{
    transform = new[] {
        0.3f,  0.3f,  0.3f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.6f,  0.6f,  0.6f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.1f,  0.1f,  0.1f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
        0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f
    }
};
```

Comment: That looks like what you want to flatten is a plain 2D array, no struct involved in the flattening. … Weirdly, I can’t find an existing straightforward question about this, although there are questions about [how to do it fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527580/how-to-convert-2-d-array-to-1-d-array-fast-in-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to flatten a 2D array into 1D, you can use [`Enumerable.Cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-7.0) method from `System.Linq`:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

var grayScale = new float[,] {
        {  0.1f,  0.2f,  0.3f },
        {  0.4f,  0.5f,  0.6f },
    };

float[] flat = grayScale.Cast<float>().ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", flat));
```

Output:

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to understand below code in c# for converting 2D array into 1D:

```
var GrayScale = new float[,] {
    {  0.3f,  0.3f,  0.3f,  0.0f,  0.0f },
    {  0.6f,  0.6f,  0.6f,  0.0f,  0.0f },
    {  0.1f,  0.1f,  0.1f,  0.0f,  0.0f },
    {  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f },
    {  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f }
};
Console.WriteLine(To1DArray(GrayScale));
Print1DArray(To1DArray(GrayScale));

static float[] To1DArray(float[,] input)
{
    // Step 1: get total size of 2D array, and allocate 1D array.
    int size = input.Length;
    float[] result = new float[size];

    // Step 2: copy 2D array elements into a 1D array.
    int write = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= input.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z <= input.GetUpperBound(1); z++)
        {
            result[write++] = input[i, z];
        }
    }
    // Step 3: return the new array.
    return result;
}

static void Print1DArray(float[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        Console.Write(arr[i] + "\t");
}
```

Output -

0.3     0.3     0.3     0       0       0.6     0.6     0.6     0       0       0.1     0.1     0.1     0       0      00       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1

for reference https://www.dotnetperls.com/flatten-array

Answer (score -1):

In order to convert a 2 dimensional array to one dimensional array without using any namespace or with simple code logic that could work in every programming language is below -

```
/* Variable Declaration */
int m=2, n=3;
int[,] a= new int[2,3] {
    {  3,  7,  9 },
    {  6,  88,  9 },
};
int[] b=new int[6];;
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
       b[k++] = a[i, j];
    }
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < m * n; i++)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t", b[i]);
 }
```

Output -

```
3   7   9   6   88  9
```

Running Fiddle Example -
https://dotnetfiddle.net/akSwDe

Comment: It wouldn't work without properly initializing `m`, `n`, and `b` (in c# for sure).

Comment: code is update now